# How to find out whether GPIO is HIGH (without RPi.GPIO module)

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I was wondering if there is a way to find out that a GPIO is under voltage, say - the GPIO is set to HIGH. I need to be able to check this in a linux terminal, using a command or a script that simply returns true or false.

I tried to use the [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) library, but I can't seem to find a function in documentation that would be able to do this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control GPIO from the command line you can use the [GPIO Sysfs Interface for Userspace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt). For example to monitor pin 26 you can do:

Prepair pin 26

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# echo 26 > /sys/class/gpio/export
rpi ~# echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio26/direction
```

Get status of pin 26

```
rpi ~# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio26/value
0
```

Finish monitoring of pin 26

```
rpi ~# echo 26 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
rpi ~# exit
rpi ~$
```

Here you can find a small script to [Continuesly monitor GPIO input change/events in Bash](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79693/79866) with `inotify`.

Answer (score 1):

Use wiringPi's gpio command.

`man gpio` for details.

Use pigpio's [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) command.

E.g.

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon

pigs r 4     # read GPIO 4
pigs w 4 1   # set GPIO 4 high
```

`man pigs` for details.